# Spring scheduler with a threadpool of 7 not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-scheduled

I have created a spring scheduler with the following code.

SchedulerConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 7;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(poolScheduler());
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("poolScheduler");
        scheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        return scheduler;
    }

}
```

Scheduler

```
package com.boilerplate.components;


import java.util.Date;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;

import com.boilerplate.services.MessageListenerService;
import java.util.Random;

//Posts Table Create Code

/**

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `legendname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `age` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


*/

//Hibernate

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class Scheduler {
//Database read and update and delete
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageListenerService.class);

    @Autowired 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron="*/6 * * * * *")
    public void doSomething() {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Random rand = new Random();
        Random f = new Random();
        Random l = new Random();
        Random a = new Random();

        int n = rand.nextInt(5000) + 1;
        int firstname = f.nextInt(5000) + 98;
        int legendname = l.nextInt(5000) + 54;
        int age = a.nextInt(5000) + 23;

        String all = Integer.toString(n)+"_"+"1200";

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("bottomlesspit", all);
        LOGGER.info("this connected....");
        LOGGER.info("Running at " + new Date());
        LOGGER.info("Current Thread : {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());       

        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","deprecation"})
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO posts(firstname,legendname,age) values(:firstname,:legendname,:age)");
        theQuery.setParameter("firstname", firstname);
        theQuery.setParameter("legendname", legendname);
        theQuery.setParameter("age",age);
        theQuery.executeUpdate();

    }

}
```

However,when i look at the console, i would expect seven threads to be outputted after every 6 seconds but its not happening. I am expecting to see 7 log messages after every 6 seconds but i only see one.

How can i make sure that all the 7 threads in the threadpool are used in the scheduler?.

Update:

```
@Async
@Scheduled(cron="*/6 * * * * *")
public void doSomething() {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Random rand = new Random();
    Random f = new Random();
    Random l = new Random();
    Random a = new Random();

    int n = rand.nextInt(5000) + 1;
    int firstname = f.nextInt(5000) + 98;
    int legendname = l.nextInt(5000) + 54;
    int age = a.nextInt(5000) + 23;

    int x = 1;

   while( x < 100 ) {

    String all = Integer.toString(n)+"_"+"1200";

    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("bottomlesspit", all);
    LOGGER.info("this connected....");
    LOGGER.info("Running at " + new Date());
    LOGGER.info("Current Thread : {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());       

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","deprecation"})
    Query theQuery = currentSession.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO posts(firstname,legendname,age) values(:firstname,:legendname,:age)");
    theQuery.setParameter("firstname", firstname);
    theQuery.setParameter("legendname", legendname);
    theQuery.setParameter("age",age);
    theQuery.executeUpdate();

  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect 7 threads to run? You schedule only one task.

Comment: @Gandalf, why do you expect  7 log messages ? Scheduled task is being executed using single thread from the Thread pool of 7. If you submit another tasks at the same time as a task is executing new thread from the pool will be used.

Comment: @Henry Oh ok . Does it mean if i loop say with a while, `int x = 1;
      while( x < 500 ) {
         System.out.print("Am i adding more tasks now?");
}`  i am adding more tasks to the queue?

Comment: @Don  I have modified the code and now i am looping. The inserts to mysql are fast. Am i making use multiple threads in the threadpool now?

Comment: @Gandalf, just add a Thread.sleep(1000); inside the loop as the last line and you will be able to see threads from the pool getting used.

Comment: @Don That's not helping ,but i can observe that it creates new threads as it goes.

Comment: @Gandalf , what do you mean by not helping ? What are you trying to achieve here ? If it is to test that threads from pool is being used if current thread is busy; you can simulate that by adding the thread sleep. Otherwise your implementation is correct and will use thread from the poll if required.

Answer (score 0):

If the current thread execution finishes it will rather recycle that thread than create a new one so that's why you keep seeing the same thread over and over - try adding a Thread.sleep in the scheduled task that sleeps for 1 minute - you should then see new threads being created as the next task gets scheduled (since the previous thread/execution will still be busy)